# Alert Ajax variable returns - city is not defined

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("https://ipinfo.io", function(response){
      var city = response.city;
      $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
      }, "jsonp");
});

alert(city);

</script>
```

Is there any possible way to convert $.get asynchronous variable to a classic one that can be printed inside div or span?

I know that usually returns promise, is there no possible way in JS to convert promise to some variable and make it global so all other functions can access it?

Comment: It's not defined when you alert it. It's defined after the ajax call gets back.

Comment: So yes: To continue, call a function where you now have `var city = response.city;`

Comment: In the API documentation of the URL you're calling, it looks like you are required to also post a token, and a more specific route. You seem to be calling the home page.